# transient Java members are not reset, when restored via t:saveState and javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to server

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, transient, tomahawk

We have an JSF1.2 Web-App using Tomahawk with `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` set to "**client**".

We use very often `<t:saveState>`  to keep the content of a bean for a longer time than one request. In order to minimize the amount of saved data, we exclude some members of the bean that is saved with the keyword `transient`:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String firstValue;
    private transient String notSerializedValue;
}
```

When this bean is reconstructed via `<t:saveState>`, the member `firstValue` will be filled with the original value, the member `notSerializedValue` will be reset to `null`;

When I  set the `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `server`, the bean member `notSerializedValue` is not reset but is also filled with the original value, when restored via `<t:saveState>`.

It seems that the bean is not serialized and deserialized, when `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is `server`.

My question:

Can I force JSF to reset my `transient` bean-members to `null`, when `STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is `server`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use the JSF SunRI. Here:  http://www.coderanch.com/t/210921/JSF/java/STATE-SAVING-METHOD I read: "Looking at the MyFaces source tonight, I was surprised to see that it "Serializes" even when saving in session mode..." Would it work if I used the MyFaces implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Using Sun-Ri you can force the ApplicationServer to serialize the managed beans with the context-parameter *com.sun.faces.serializeServerState* in web.xml. I tested it and then my transient members had been reset in every request:

```
<context-param>
         <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
         <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.faces.serializeServerState</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I also found this parameter *org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION* that seems to fit to MyFaces, but I could not test ist:

```
<context-param>
         <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```